# How to solve this exponential/diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

The equation is: $$
2^x3^{x-1}=y\cdot3^{x-1}\cdot2+z\cdot2^{x-1}$$ for natural numbers.

I’ve tried to divide this expression or try various substitutions, but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you find any solutions? Do your natural numbers include zero?

Comment: Note that $z$ must have a factor $3^{x-1}$ so divide that out.  Now $y$ needs a factor $2^{x-2}$

Comment: I’ve guessed some solutions, e.g.: (2, 2, 9). My definition of natural numbers doesn’t include zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume natural numbers don't include $0$ for simplicity.

If $x=1$, then $2=2y+z$, which has no solution, as $2y+z\ge 2 + 1 = 3$.

Assume $x\ge2$, then $3^{x-1} | z\cdot 2^{x-1}$, therefore $3^{x-1} | z$, so $z=3^{x-1}c$ for some natural number $c$. Similarly, $2^{x-1}|2y$, $y=2^{x-2}b$, therefore the equation becomes $4=2b+2c$ which has a unique solution $b=c=1$. Therefore, the general solution is just $(x, 2^{x-2}, 3^{x-1})$.

So the solutions are $\{(x, 2^{x-2}, 3^{x-1}) \mid x\in\mathbb N, x\ge 2\}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{array} {}
  2^x3^{x-1} &= y \cdot 3^{x-1}\cdot 2 + z \cdot 2^{x-1} & \text {use $w$ for $x-1$} \\
2 \cdot 2^w 3^w &= y \cdot 3^w\cdot 2 + z \cdot 2^w \\
2 \cdot 3^w \cdot(2^w-y) &=  z \cdot 2^w  &\implies z=z_1 3^w\\
2 \cdot 3^w \cdot(2^w-y) &=  z_1 \cdot 3^w \cdot 2^w \\
2 \cdot(2^w-y) &=  z_1 \cdot 2^w \\
 2^w  \cdot (2-z_1)&=  2 \cdot y &\implies y=y_1 \cdot 2^{w-1} \\
2= y_1 + z_1 & \land y,z \in \mathbb N &\implies y_1=z_1=1 \\
 \implies \\
(4y,3z)&=(2^x,3^x) & \text{ insert & check! } \\
2^x3^{x-1} &= 2^{x-2} \cdot 3^{x-1}\cdot 2 + 3^{x-1} \cdot 2^{x-1} \\
2^x3^{x-1} &= 2^{x-1} \cdot 3^{x-1} + 3^{x-1} \cdot 2^{x-1} \\
2^x &= 2^{x-1}  + 2^{x-1} = 2^x & \implies \text{result is correct!} \\
\end{array}
$$